# Bokeh HoverTool with multiple plots

Tags: python, hover, bokeh

I try to make a dashboard with bokeh but my hover tool got broken, since I tried to plot the data in a single diagram. I found some answers to this problem, but unfortunately I can't adapt it to my code.
I want to be able to turn off and on the visibility of data.
(Another problem is, that the whole plot vanishes, if you change the daterange to an area, where no values exist, maybe someone has a workaround for this. In an older version I tried to only change source emit, when range is on data, but this leads to other problems. Maybe someone has an idea for that too.)
Here is a reduced minimal working version of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

from bokeh.models import Button, CheckboxGroup, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, DatetimeTickFormatter, HoverTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import DateRangeSlider
from bokeh.layouts import layout, column, row
from bokeh.palettes import Category20
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

datesX = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=100) #incl. '2018-01-01' to '2018-04-10'
numbof = 3
datesX = datesX[0:10].union(datesX[20:100])
valuesY = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(90, numbof)), columns=list((f'V{i}' for i in range(numbof))))
movingY = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(90, numbof)), columns=list((f'M{i}' for i in range(numbof))))

preCDS ={}

for i in range(numbof):
    preCDS.update({f'x{i}': datesX})
    preCDS.update({f'y{i}': valuesY[f'V{i}']})
    preCDS.update({f'm{i}': movingY[f'M{i}']})
    
source = ColumnDataSource(preCDS) 
source2 = ColumnDataSource(preCDS)

# output to static HTML file
output_file('file.html')

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(
    title='file1', x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='yValue',
    y_range=(0, 30), x_axis_type='datetime',
    tools="pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset, save",
    plot_width=1800, plot_height=480)

ypsilon = [f'y{i}' for i in range(numbof)]
em = [f'm{i}' for i in range(numbof)]

hover = HoverTool(line_policy='nearest', names=ypsilon + em,
    tooltips=[('Timestamp', '@x{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'), ('Wert', '@y')], ###what to do with @x and @y to make it iterable: x0, x1, x2, y0, ...
    formatters={'@x': 'datetime'})

p.add_tools(hover)

date_range_slider = DateRangeSlider(
    title="DateRange", start=datesX[0], end=datesX[89],
    value=(datesX[0], datesX[89]), width=800, bar_color = (32,120,180))

checkbox_vals = CheckboxGroup(labels=[f'Plot {i+1}' for i in range(numbof)], active=[i for i in range(numbof)])
checkbox_mova = CheckboxGroup(labels=[f'Plot {i+1}' for i in range(numbof)], active=[i for i in range(numbof)])

vals=[]
mova=[]

for i in range(numbof):
    vals.append(p.circle(x=f'x{i}', y=f'y{i}', source=source, color = Category20[20][2*i], size=3, name=f'y{i}'))
    mova.append(p.line(x=f'x{i}', y=f'm{i}', source=source, line_color = Category20[20][2*i+1], line_width=2, name=f'm{i}'))


rangeCallback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ref_source=source2, dRs=date_range_slider), code="""
        
    // print out array of date from, date to
    //console.log(dRs.value); 

    // dates returned from slider are not at round intervals and include time
    const date_from = Date.parse(new Date(dRs.value[0]).toDateString());
    const date_to = Date.parse(new Date(dRs.value[1]).toDateString());
    //console.log(date_from, date_to)

    // Creating the Data Sources
    const data = source.data;
    const ref = ref_source.data;

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        console.log(key)
        // Creating new Array and appending correctly parsed dates
        if(key.indexOf("x") == 0){
            let new_ref = [];
            let from_pos = [];
            let to_pos = [];
            
            ref[key].forEach(elem => {
                elem = Date.parse(new Date(elem).toDateString()); 
                new_ref.push(elem);
            })
            
            // Creating Indices with new Array
            from_pos[key] = new_ref.indexOf(date_from);
            to_pos[key] = new_ref.indexOf(date_to) + 1;

            // re-create the source data from "reference"
            const dataKeyM = key.replace('x', 'm');
            const dataKeyY = key.replace('x', 'y');
            
            data[dataKeyM] = ref[dataKeyM].slice(from_pos[key], to_pos[key]);
            data[key] = ref[key].slice(from_pos[key], to_pos[key]);
            data[dataKeyY] = ref[dataKeyY].slice(from_pos[key], to_pos[key]);
        }
    }
    /*if (new_ref.includes(date_from) && new_ref.includes(date_to)) {
        source.change.emit();
    }*/
    source.change.emit();  
    
    """)

checkboxValsCallback = CustomJS(args=dict(vals=vals, checkboxVals=checkbox_vals), code="""

    var indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { 
        for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { 
            if (i in this && this[i] === item) 
                return i; 
            } 
        return -1; 
    };
    
    //vals.visible = indexOf.call(checkboxVals.active,0)>=0;
    for (let i=0;i<vals.length;i++) {
        vals[i].visible = indexOf.call(checkboxVals.active,i)>=0;
    }
    
    """)

checkboxMovaCallback = CustomJS(args=dict(mova=mova, checkboxMova=checkbox_mova), code="""

    var indexOf = [].indexOf || function(item) { 
        for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { 
            if (i in this && this[i] === item) 
                return i; 
            } 
        return -1; 
    };
    
    //mova.visible = indexOf.call(checkboxMova.active,0)>=0;
    for (let i=0;i<mova.length;i++) {
        mova[i].visible = indexOf.call(checkboxMova.active,i)>=0;
    }
    
    """)

checkbox_vals.js_on_change('active', checkboxValsCallback)
checkbox_mova.js_on_change('active', checkboxMovaCallback)
date_range_slider.js_on_change('value', rangeCallback)

b1 = Button(label="select all", max_width = 300, button_type="primary")
b1.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(s=checkbox_vals, t=checkbox_mova), code="""
    s.active = [0,1,2]
    t.active = [0,1,2]
    """))

b2 = Button(label="unselect all", max_width = 300)
b2.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(s=checkbox_vals, t=checkbox_mova), code="""
    s.active = []
    t.active = []
    """))

layout = column(p, row(checkbox_vals, checkbox_mova, date_range_slider), row(b1, b2))
show(layout)
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: You should ask one problem a time

Answer (score 0):

For the tooltips: you specified `x` and `y` for the hover but when you look at the datasource of e.g. your line glyphs stored in `mova` you will see there is no `x` or `y` but many different fields. I changed the tooltips to `x1` and `y0` but I am not sure if this is wat you want. Just put a breakpoint somewhere and look e.g. in the `mova[0].data_source.data` and you will see all the available fields and choose the ones you want for your tooltips.

```
hover = HoverTool(line_policy='nearest', names=ypsilon + em,
                  tooltips=[('Timestamp', '@x1{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'), ('Wert', '@y0')],
                  formatters={'@x1': 'datetime'})
```